# boost::iostreams::::copy Seems Excessively Slow

Tags: c++, boost

I am using `boost::iostreams::::copy` in it's common role of as part compressing a stream in memory. However, it seems excessively slow when copying a rather large compressed stream: ~30 MB may take ~2 minutes.

Here is my code:

```
std::stringstream compress(std::stringstream& data)
{
    namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

    std::stringstream comp;
    bio::filtering_streambuf<bio::input> out;
    out.push(bio::gzip_compressor(bio::gzip_params(bio::gzip::best_compression)));
    out.push(data);
    bio::copy(out, comp);

    return comp;
}
```

The culprit is the line:

```
bio::copy(out, comp);
```

The data is in bytes and contains NULs if that matters but I need to use `std::stringstream`.

Does anyone see an issue with my code or have suggestions on what may improve my code? Perhaps it just takes that long though it seems excessive.

Comment: Make sure you are using an optimized build. On Visual Studio I have seen cases where a Debug build took 100 times as long as Release.

Answer (score 0):

In a stunning- no, jaw-dropping- turn of events, it seems `bio::gzip::best_compression` is the real culprit.

When I changed it to `bio::gzip::best_speed`, I got these (rough) results:

```
bio::gzip::best_compression: output size 6589968 bytes     elapsed time: 105881 ms
bio::gzip::best_speed: output size: 6589596 bytes     elapsed time: 6065 ms
```

So it seems in my case (without regard to exactly why- probably the nature of the data) the answer is to change compression level.

Note: That's with VC++ 2017 in debug.

Comment: Why is it surprising that switching to a speed-optimised mode would be faster? And I'll reiterate what drescherjm said: benchmarking/measuring in debug is _utterly pointless_. Debug is deliberately slow, and it may be more slow in some code configurations than in others, in ways that do not directly relate to the documented semantics of the code configuration. In other words, you are likely to see a much smaller difference between the two modes if you measure in release like you're supposed to :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. In fact, I came upon the issue in the first place while testing a release build. It was indeed terribly slow in release though I didn't get exact measurements. I was not surprised that the speed-optimized mode would be faster, I was surprised by the _degree_ to which it is faster while producing essentially the same results as the compression-optimized mode.

Comment: You literally told us that your benchmark was from a debug build.